# how to use TCP_QUICKACK uder fedora 17

Tags: c++, c, linux, tcp

Hi I am tring to use TCP_QUICKACK under fedora core 17 
but like below

```
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, (int[]){1}, sizeof(int))
```

but when I try to compile it I get

error: ‘TCP_QUICKACK’ undeclared

what I need to do 
pls help

Comment: It's a Christmas quacker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a copy of Fedora handy, but under Ubuntu 12.04, TCP_QUICKACK is defined in netinet/tcp.h (and in linux/tcp.h).

You can probably find the correct header by using the following shell command:

```
find /usr/include -name "*.h" | xargs grep TCP_QUIKACK
```

(If you system doesn't use /usr/include, substitute the correct path.)

*[edit: remove extra zero from Ubuntu version.]*